# How can I start a service of an app when the device boots? (Android)

Tags: java, android

How can I write a `service`, which starts automatically when the `device boots`? For example: when I start my phone, I get my new `WhatsApp` Messages, without opening `WhatsApp` before.

Answer (score 1):

Two addition to Himanshu's answer:

- A boot-listening app **must not be installed on the sdcard**. Remember that the device boot may be completed 
  before the sdcard is even mounted resulting in your app's boot listener not being activated
- **The boot-listener will not be activated until the user will activate your
  app for the first time**. Starting 4.2 (not sure here) android prevents all services & 
  listeners declared by a newly installed app from being activated until it is explicitly activated by the user.

Explicitly activated as in user clicking the homescreen icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make it working:

Your `manifest` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.jjoe64">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application>
        <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Add this class `BootCompletedIntentReceiver.java`

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

this will make it auto start your service after boot of device

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the `Intent` in the `BroadcastReceiver`? Why don't you use the corresponding constant `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`? Also indent you code with 4 spaces, not one... I already fixed your formatting this time.